# How to run a SQL query automatically on Date basis?

Tags: c#, sql-server, triggers

I want to run a timely based query that will run every day at a given time.
How can I do it?
Can it be possible with trigger?

Comment: What type of DB? This is fairly common question, if Oracle DB, then look into dbms_jobs. I think this was asked just ealier today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement in **SQL Server** you should go for **SQL Job**.
It is fairly simple to set up, create your query as a stored procedure and while configuring your job in step write

`EXEC YourStoredProcedureName`

You can set a job in **SQL Server** using **SQL server Management Studio**. It needs additional rights to view that section in management studio so if not visible you can ask admin guys to give access.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQL Server Agent job & make schedule to recurring job every day at your desired time.

Comment: Hi didn't say he talks about SQL Server

Comment: Man. He tagged SQL in question.! So obviously, It is SQL. :)

Comment: Yes, its about SQL Server, and I am going with it. Thanks @PratikPatel

Comment: @PratikPatel - SQL is NOT the same as SQL Server. SQL is common language for all relational databases. There is separate tag for SQL Server. Just because Microsoft tend to use generic words in names of their products it doesn't mean we may be ignorant about it.

Answer (score 1):

Various database systems have different mechanisms of performing Jobs and in fact both Oracle and SQL Server have jobs that - in easiest scenario - will run a procedure at particular period of time and may be recurring or not.

If you don't have enough access to the SQL Server, you can always explore outside database scenarios. On Windows you have Windows tasks which can periodically run simple console application that could run whatever query you want. On Linux you have CRON that can work similarly. The built-in functionality is - however - preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Create cron job for it.

check this: http://blog.bobcravens.com/2009/10/an-event-based-cron-scheduled-job-in-c/